# How to use the "native" UI look and feel with React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native, flatlist

I find it interesting to use React Native, but currently I just have one pain point:

The native look and feel of e.g. a iOS List.

So if I create a SwiftUI App in XCode and add a List with some text it looks like an native iOS list. But If I create a React Native app with an `FlatList` and then run in on my iPhone, it just looks like a list with absolutly no style.

Is there and plugin or whatever to get the "native" iOS 14 look and feel?

Comment: You should style it yourself. Style your component inside your `renderItem` the way you want it to.

Comment: but this is what i dont want, i just want to have the default ios14 style. is this possible?

Comment: react-native is not build of swiftUI component. Maybe you could check this out and configure it yourself -> https://medium.com/better-programming/react-native-meets-swiftui-d1606a8e1681